# Mono: how to run a bash command on a new console/terminal window?

Tags: c#, linux, bash, terminal, mono

How can I run a bash command using Mono (System.Diagnostics.Process) in a new console/terminal window? It works fine on Windows, where a new console window is opened to run the command. On Linux and macOS, the command runs on the same terminal window which I've used to open the app. I've tried all CreateNoWindow/UseShellExecute combinations but none of them worked for me.

Edit: here's the code:

```
                    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                switch (ThermoCS.PlatformCheck.RunningPlatform())
                {
                    case ThermoCS.PlatformCheck.Platform.Windows:
                        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                        startInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\ThermoCS\\" + item.Key + ".exe";
                        if (item.Key.Contains("1"))
                        {
                            startInfo.Arguments = Model;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            startInfo.Arguments = Model + " " + MixRule;
                        }
                        break;
                    case ThermoCS.PlatformCheck.Platform.Linux:
                        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                        var ldc = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/ThermoCS/; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH";
                        //startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                        startInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
                        if (item.Key.Contains("1"))
                        {
                            startInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + ldc + " && chmod +x ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " && ./ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " " + Model + " \"";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            startInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + ldc + " && chmod +x ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " && ./ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " " + Model + " " + MixRule + " \"";
                        }
                        break;
                    case ThermoCS.PlatformCheck.Platform.Mac:
                        var basedir = Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).Parent.FullName;
                        var ldcosx = "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + basedir + "/Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/";
                        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = basedir;
                        //startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                        startInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
                        if (item.Key.Contains("1"))
                        {
                            startInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + ldcosx + " && chmod +x Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " && ./Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " " + Model + " \"";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            startInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + ldcosx + " && chmod +x Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " && ./Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " " + Model + " " + MixRule + " \"";
                        }
                        break;
                }
                Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

As I've described above, the command runs just fine. The problem is that on Linux and macOS it does on the same terminal window which owns the currently running app. I want it to run on a new terminal window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your code - because chances are you didnt do what you think you did

Comment: Then i was right - and no point did you ask it to open a new window - just run another copy of bash - which if you run from any given command line doesnt open a window...

Comment: Which is why I'm asking for help on how to do it the correct way.

Comment: Well - I assume you're using xwindows because you want to open a new "window" xterm is the given way to get a window on xwindows... you'd need to run one of those .. for a mac less sure Im not digging mine out of a box to find out - as Im not a mac person - your code is probably doing exactly what it should it started a shell and did things..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself. It involves saving the commands in a script file, making it executable and calling **xterm** on Linux or **Terminal.app** on macOS:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
switch (ThermoCS.PlatformCheck.RunningPlatform())
{
    case ThermoCS.PlatformCheck.Platform.Windows:
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        startInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\ThermoCS\\" + item.Key + ".exe";
        if (item.Key.Contains("1"))
        {
            startInfo.Arguments = Model;
        }
        else
        {
            startInfo.Arguments = Model + " " + MixRule;
        }
        break;
    case ThermoCS.PlatformCheck.Platform.Linux:
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        var ldc = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/ThermoCS/; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH";
        var scriptl = new StringBuilder();
        scriptl.AppendLine("#!/bin/bash");
        scriptl.AppendLine("cd '" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "'");
        scriptl.AppendLine(ldc);
        scriptl.AppendLine("chmod +x ThermoCS/" + item.Key);
        if (item.Key.Contains("1"))
        {
            scriptl.AppendLine("./ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " " + Model);
        }
        else
        {
            scriptl.AppendLine("./ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " " + Model + " " + MixRule);
        }
        var filepathl = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllText(filepathl, scriptl.ToString());
        Process.Start("/bin/bash", "-c \" chmod +x " + filepathl + " \"");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "xterm";
        startInfo.Arguments = "-e '" + filepathl + "'";
        break;
    case ThermoCS.PlatformCheck.Platform.Mac:
        var basedir = Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).Parent.FullName;
        var ldcosx = "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + basedir + "/Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/";
        var script = new StringBuilder();
        script.AppendLine("#!/bin/bash");
        script.AppendLine("cd '" + basedir + "'");
        script.AppendLine(ldcosx);
        script.AppendLine("chmod +x Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/" + item.Key);
        if (item.Key.Contains("1"))
        {
            script.AppendLine("./Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " " + Model);
        }
        else
        {
            script.AppendLine("./Contents/MonoBundle/ThermoCS/" + item.Key + " " + Model + " " + MixRule);
        }
        var filepath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllText(filepath, script.ToString());
        Process.Start("/bin/bash", "-c \" chmod +x " + filepath + " \"");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "open";
        startInfo.Arguments = "-a Terminal.app " + filepath;
        break;
}
Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was I wrote a simple bash script that I placed in my Debug/Release/Whatever folder (folder of the executable of C# program.) Lets call the bash script, first.sh

In this bash folder, I would call another bash from another directory, the bash I was looking to run initially. Lets call this bash script, second.sh

In my C# code I will call  first.sh like this:

```
 string command = string.Format("{0}", "./first.sh");
        Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "gnome-terminal";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " -e  \" " + command + " \"";

        proc.Start();
```

My first.sh would change to the directory where my second.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a comment!
echo hello world        # This is just a test to see if it is being called
cd ~
cd home/scripts
(exec "./second")
```

This whole process would physically open up a new terminal and execute commands within it from C# code.

Here is a good tutorial on how to write bash scripts: [tutorial on bash scripting in linux](https://www.shellscript.sh/first.html)